# buildroot file rights in filesystem overlay not preserved

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, buildroot

I am making a buildroot system with an ssh server and I would like to fix the ssh keys used by the server by adding them in my filesystem overlay. the private keys need to have limited rights (read write for the owner and nothing else).

when I build, those rights are changed in target filesystem and the ssh server don't start because rights are too open.

```
$ ls -lh ./rootfs_overlay/etc/ssh
total 596K
-rw-r--r-- 1 william william 553K sept. 12 10:46 moduli
-rw-r--r-- 1 william william 1,5K sept. 12 10:46 ssh_config
-rw-r--r-- 1 william william 3,1K sept. 26 11:27 sshd_config
-rw------- 1 william william 1,4K oct.   3 16:22 ssh_host_dsa_key
-rw-r--r-- 1 william william  604 oct.   3 16:22 ssh_host_dsa_key.pub
-rw------- 1 william william  505 oct.   3 16:22 ssh_host_ecdsa_key
-rw-r--r-- 1 william william  176 oct.   3 16:22 ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
-rw------- 1 william william  411 oct.   3 16:22 ssh_host_ed25519_key
-rw-r--r-- 1 william william   96 oct.   3 16:22 ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
-rw------- 1 william william 1,8K oct.   3 16:22 ssh_host_rsa_key
-rw-r--r-- 1 william william  396 oct.   3 16:22 ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
$ ls -lh ./output/target/etc/ssh/
total 596K
-rw-r--r-- 1 william william 553K sept. 12 10:46 moduli
-rw-r--r-- 1 william william 1,5K sept. 12 10:46 ssh_config
-rw-r--r-- 1 william william 3,1K sept. 26 11:27 sshd_config
-rw-r--r-- 1 william william 1,4K oct.   3 16:22 ssh_host_dsa_key
-rw-r--r-- 1 william william  604 oct.   3 16:22 ssh_host_dsa_key.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 william william  505 oct.   3 16:22 ssh_host_ecdsa_key
-rw-r--r-- 1 william william  176 oct.   3 16:22 ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 william william  411 oct.   3 16:22 ssh_host_ed25519_key
-rw-r--r-- 1 william william   96 oct.   3 16:22 ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 william william 1,8K oct.   3 16:22 ssh_host_rsa_key
-rw-r--r-- 1 william william  396 oct.   3 16:22 ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
```

buildroot is using rsync for this transfer and is supposed to preserve rights. I don't know what I can do to preserve those rights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the permission table feature to set custom file permissions:
https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#customize-device-permission

Or for more complicated things you can use a post-fakeroot script as explained here:
https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#rootfs-custom

Comment: Thank you ! adding a permission table resolved my problem.